# Capturing error message of curl in BASH script andchecking status

Tags: bash, curl

**I need 4 things from curl in a BASH script:**

- I need to capture **brief** humanly readable error message from curl into a bash variable.
- I need to be able to check that the command completed
  successfully or not.
- I need the command to run
- I don't want anything printed to console unless I echo it.

> ```
> m=$(curl -u "$user":AP"$pass" -T "$pathA" "$url")
> if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then
>    echo "Error: ""$m"
> fi
> ```

The problem is curl puts gibberish into $m.  It just dumps the error to console instead of m.  I don't want anything printed to console unless I echo it. And I only want to capture error descriptions.  I tried many variations, nothing seemed to work for this use-case... at least nothing suggested here on Stack.

Comment: You are using *command substitution* to capture ALL output from `curl` in `m` except you are not capturing `stderr`. Add `2>&1` at the end of your `curl` command, e.g. `..."$url" 2>&1)` Also `echo "Error: $m"` is sufficient.

Comment: That's right -- you should make that an answer so it can be marked correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`curl` sends errors to STDERR and will **not** get captured by `$m`. The output of `curl` is sent to STDERR (that gibberish you mentioned).

One solution is to redirect STDERR to STDOUT by adding `2>&1` to your `curl` invocation in your script:

```
m=$(curl -u "$user":AP"$pass" -T "$pathA" "$url" 2>&1)
if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then
   echo "Error: ""$m"
fi
```

You could also use the `--fail`, `--silent` and `--show-errors` flags of `curl` like in this example if all you care about are the errors:

[Making curl send errors to stderr and everything else to stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6935006/making-curl-send-errors-to-stderr-and-everything-else-to-stdout)

and some information about capturing STDERR to `$variable` in bash scripts:

[Bash how do you capture stderr to a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11087499/bash-how-do-you-capture-stderr-to-a-variable)

Answer (score 0):

Similar to one suggested; I m just using the output stderror as $? is always 0.

```
OUTPUT=$(curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data "{\"text\":\"$MSG \"}" $SLACK_URL 2>1)
echo $OUTPUT
if [[ $OUTPUT == "ok" ]]; then
  echo "$FILE_NAME Msg successfully sent"
elif [[ $OUTPUT == "invalid_token" ]]; then
  echo "$FILE_NAME Slack url incorrect"
else
  echo "$FILE_NAME Some issue Sending msg"
fi
```